# Did I set up this Newtons Method problem correctly?

Tags: calculus

First off I want to say that this is homework. So please don't give me the answer. I'm just looking for guidance and confirmation of whether I have the right idea.

Please forgive me as I don't know how the syntax works on this site yet. But my problem reads

The revenue from the sale of $x$ thousand textbooks is given by $f(s) = 10xe^{-0.05x}$. How many textbooks must be sold to generate $\$60,000$.

The first thing I did was set up my equation: $10xe^{-0.05x} - 60$

The next thing I did was set up my derivative: $e^{-0.05x} \times (10 - 0.5x)$

Then I picked a number ($45$) and plugged it in to both the equation and derivative and set it up to resemble Newton's method ($x - (f/f')$) and it resulted in $35.45$. I plugged it in a few more times and the resulting number was $35.62$.

So am I correct in stating that the number of textbooks that must be sold to generate $\$60,000$ is around $36,000$ textbooks?

I'm sorry about the formatting. I'm going to try and learn it for future questions.

Comment: Without doing any calculations myself, you look like you're doing it correctly.

Comment: "I don't know how the syntax works on this site". For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: You can check by substitution that $35.62$ is close. One cannot say much more without seeing full details, but the beginning was right. You mention an equation and there is no equal sign, but prsumably you meant $=0$.

Comment: Thank you America Tavares for the links. I will look into the syntax and sure I do it on my next question. rlgordonma and Andre Nicolas thank you for the confirmation. I'm glad I'm heading in the right direction. I did mean 0, you are correct in your assumption.